# how come aSet.add(something) updates the original set even its done in a different function?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def inheriting():
    results = set()

    resultsAdd(results)

    print(results)
    return None

def resultsAdd(results):
    results.add("3")

    return None

inheriting()
```

here for example, i expected inheriting() it to print an empty set. if i change it to

> results = "someString"

and did `results = "otherString"` to that in `resultsAdd(results)`

it just prints "someString".

I want to learn more about this but I don't know what i would look for. Can someone explain or tell me where I can learn more about these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not read the tuturial that comes with python, you should do so.  But here is a summary explanation of this common newbie question.

First part: An assignment statement like `a = <expression1>` connects name `a` with the object resulting from evaluating `<expression1>`.  Given `def f(a): pass`, `f(<expression1>)` connects parameter name `a` with the object resulting from evaluating `<expression1>`.  In both cases, object1 is not copied.

Second: if object a is a set, `def f(a): a.add(<expression2>)` mutates (changes) object a by adding object2, resulting from evaluating `<expression2>`, to the set.  On the other hand, `def f(a): a = <expression2>`, ignores the original object1 and rebinds local name `a` to object2.